# How to debug xhr onerror in firefox

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am currently working on a browser extension that is supposed to be able to make HTTP requests to a remote server (ie on an EC2 instance). I keep on trying the code below but it keeps failing and triggering the onerror() event. How can I find out what is causing the event or prevent the request from actually happening. Any help will be really appreciated

Content Script:

```js
function getAddressBarURL() {
    url = window.location.href;

    console.log('Captured URL');
    return url;
}

const isValidUrl = urlString=> {
    var urlPattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // validate protocol
  '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // validate domain name
  '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // validate OR ip (v4) address
  '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // validate port and path
  '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // validate query string
  '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // validate fragment locator
return !!urlPattern.test(urlString);
}

const request_url = getAddressBarURL();


if(isValidUrl(request_url)) {
    console.log('Sending Message to Background Script');
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({'url': request_url});
}
```

Background Script

```js
console.log("Extension Loaded");

function verifyURL(message) {
    console.log("Message From Content Script Recieved");
    console.log(message);

    const server_url = "ec2-44-204-184-249.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/predict";
    console.log("Create XHR objecy");
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhr.open("POST", server_url);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => { // Call a function when the state changes.
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
          console.log(xhr.response);
        } else {
            return('Maybe Error');
        }
    }

    xhr.onerror = function (err) {
        console.log("** An error occurred during the transaction");
        console.log(err);
        console.log(err.target.status);
        console.log(xhr.readyState);
    };

    console.log("Send Request")
    xhr.send(message.url);

}


browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(verifyURL);
```

Console Logs:
[image: Console Logs]

**UPDATE MANIFEST.JSON**

```json
{

  "description": "URL Classifier determines whether the URL the user is about to access is malicious or not",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "URL Classifier",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/shield-ok-icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background-script.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content_scripts/content.js"]
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/shield-ok-icon.png",
    "default_title": "URL Classifier",
    "default_popup": "popup/view_statistics.html"
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Thats the thing @Yogi , nothing shows up or gets logged out. Kindly refer to the picture for the output of the onerror() function. Output of

Comment: I would guess that it is not a CORS error as you would see that in the console. Did you configure [permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions) correctly in your Firefox extension manifest.json?

Comment: Yes I did @Yogi, or atleast I hope so.

Comment: Ive added the maifest.json file in the question

Comment: I recreated your extension. The problem appears to be with your endpoint. The request times out and does nothing. However, if I switch to a url that I know works then request completes as expected. So the problem appears to be with the url or how the aws endpoint is configured.  Yet, that's not a question we can answer from the information in the question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help @Yogi . Let me try to recheck my EC2 instance configuration or try to use a different URL because when I try to test my endpoints availability using postman, the request goes through without any problems that is when my EC2 instance is is up and running.